# Regex to get the first 6 digit number coming in square bracket

Tags: python, regex

I have a string.

```
確認いただきありがとうございます。あなたのピンは[123456]幸せなブラウジングです .
```

I need to get the 6 digit number coming in the square bracket. Please help me with regex. I am trying in python. The text can be sometimes Japanese or French or Thai.

Comment: `(?<=\[)\d{6}(?=])`

Comment: `re.search('\[(.*?)\]', '確認いただきありがとうございます。あなたのピンは[123456]幸せなブラウジングです . ').group(1)`

Comment: @Hrishi `[^\]]*` is better than lazy quantifier.